# Prove that ${1\over2}<{1\over1001}+......+{1\over2000}<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that ${1\over2}<{1\over1001}+......+{1\over2000}<1$

Can it be proved by langrange's mean value theorem or by convert it into a Riemann sum?

Comment: **Hint:** You're vastly overkilling it.

Comment: Why proving that a finite sum is in $(0.5,1)$? Just calculate the value and you're done.

Comment: similar http://math.stackexchange.com/q/688432/129458

Answer (score 14):

$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1000}{2000}<\underbrace{\frac{1}{1001}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2000}}_{1000 \text{  terms}}<\frac{1000}{1000}=1$$